# Using XPath contains() gets too much results

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML-file where some sub-trees are marked with ID-Tags

```
<root>
  <A>
    <someid>5</someid>
    ...
  </A>
  <B>
    <someid>15</someid>
    ...
  </B>
</root>
```

If I try to find a sub-tree by this id with the help of XPath `contains()` I, obviously, ran into trouble with numbers like 5 and 15:

```
//someid[ contains( text(), "5" ) ]
```

I tried to use `matches()` but it's not supported.

Any ideas how to tackle this without matches?

Comment: You don't want contains("5"), you want ="5"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//someid[text()="5"]
```

I'm not sure which language you use, so I'll demonstrate in PHP:

```php
$str=<<<XML
<root>
  <A>
    <someid>5</someid>
  </A>
  <B>
    <someid>15</someid>
  </B>
</root>
XML;
$xml=simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xml->xpath('//someid[text()="5"]') as $node)
{
    echo $node;
}
```

Outputs `5`.

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/9jljb)

Answer (score 1):

If you IDs are all numbers, you can use

```
//someid[number()=5]
```

You can as well use matches() and a regexp

```
//someid[matches(text(),"^5$")]
```